# domain name and subdomain pointing to default apache and webmin

Tags: networking, server, dns, routing, port-forwarding

I have recently setup Ubuntu Server 18.04 on an old but still decent laptop.
Have installed apache2, php, mysql etc. and webmin.

Have done the port forwarding  in my router and when I access my external IP in a browser it takes me to default appache and I am able to access webmin on port 10000 with my external IP.

So all good until now....but...

I have also bought a domain name, let's call it google.com, and setup DNS with Cloudfare. I have forwarded on Cloudfare myserver.google.com and google.com to my external IP.

I have changed hosts file and added:

```
externalIP google.com myserver
externalIP:10000 myserver.google.com myserver
```

What I really want to do is when I access google.com to point to default apache and when I access diablo.google.com to point to webmin.

Pretty sure I'm doing something very wrong but still learning :)

Thanks!

Comment: DNS lookups include only IP addresses and domain names, not ports.

Comment: You can use proxy pass to get around the port issue.